# iOS SimplePingDelegate callback methods are not firing

Tags: ios, swift, networking

I need to ping a hostname in my iOS app via SimplePing Library. Delegate methods not firing after pinger?.start() is called.

```swift
    //code to actually ping

    var pinger: SimplePing?
    var canStartPinging = false

    func ping() {
        pinger = SimplePing(hostName: "www.apple.com")        
        pinger?.delegate = self
        pinger?.start()

        repeat {
            print("Repeat loop \(String(describing: 
    pinger?.hostName))")

            if (canStartPinging) {
                pinger?.send(with: nil)
            }
            RunLoop.current.run(mode: RunLoop.Mode.default, before: 
    (NSDate.distantFuture ))
        } while(pinger != nil)
    }

    //SimplePingDelegate Methods below

    extension WelcomeViewController: SimplePingDelegate {
    private func simplePing(pinger: SimplePing!, didFailToSendPacket 
    packet: NSData!, error: NSError!) {
        print("didFailToSendPacket")
    }

    private func simplePing(pinger: SimplePing, didFailWithError error: 
    NSError) {
        print("didFailWithError")
    }

    private func simplePing(pinger: SimplePing!, 
    didReceivePingResponsePacket packet: NSData!) {
        print("didReceivePingResponsePacket")
    }

    private func simplePing(pinger: SimplePing!, 
    didReceiveUnexpectedPacket packet: NSData!) {
        print("didReceiveUnexpectedPacket")
    }

    private func simplePing(pinger: SimplePing!, didSendPacket packet: 
    NSData!) {
        print("didSendPacket")
    }


    private  func simplePing(pinger: SimplePing!, didStartWithAddress 
    address: NSData!) {
        print("didStartWithAddress : \(String(describing: address))")
        canStartPinging = true
        }
    }
```

Not receiving callbacks from delegate. The loop runs but nothing happens. Prints "Repeat loop Optional("www.apple.com")" and never prints didStartWithAddress nor didFailWithError.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out method signature for delegate methods was incorrect. The best way to populate delegate methods is to start typing simplePing and allow Xcode to suggest method completion options!